# ggplot & Confidence Intervals for Holt-Winters Prediction Function

Tags: r, ggplot2, prediction, confidence-interval, holtwinters

Using data `UKDriverDeaths`

Attempting to use Holt-Winters prediction function & `ggplot()`.

Basically reproduce the data in `ggplot` (1) with confidence intervals (2).

This is the data:

```
data('UKDriverDeaths')    
past <- window(UKDriverDeaths, end = c(1982, 12))
hw <- HoltWinters(past)
pred <- predict(hw, n.ahead = 10)
plot(hw, pred, ylim = range(UKDriverDeaths))
lines(UKDriverDeaths)
```

This is solution (1) to creating it in `ggplot()`:

```
library(xts)
ts_pred <- ts(c(hw$fitted[, 1], pred), start = 1970, frequency = 12)
df <- merge(as.xts(ts_pred), as.xts(UKDriverDeaths))
names(df) <- c("predicted", "actual")
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.POSIXct(index(df)))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=predicted), col='red') + 
  geom_line(aes(y=actual), col='black') + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.POSIXct("1982-12-01")), linetype="dashed") + 
  labs(title="Holt-Winters filtering\n", x="Time", y="Observed / Fitted") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"))
```

I'm looking for confidence intervals (2) for holt-winters prediction.

Comment: If you do `?predict.HoltWinters` the two arguments you need to add to get confidence intervals will be apparent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically you call confidence intervals for predictions "prediction intervals". The `predict.HoltWinters` function will give those to you if you ask for them with `prediction.interval=T`. So you can do

```
pred <- predict(hw, n.ahead = 10, prediction.interval = TRUE)
```

Now this will change the shape of the values returned. Rather than a simple vector, you get a matrix, so you'll need to adjust some of your other transformation code to deal with this. Try

```
ts_pred <- ts(rbind(cbind(hw$fitted[, 1],upr=NA,lwr=NA), pred), 
    start = 1970, frequency = 12)
df <- merge(as.xts(UKDriverDeaths), as.xts(ts_pred))
names(df)[1:2] <- c("actual", "predicted")
```

This attempts to make sure all the columns get correctly lined up and labeled between the observed values and the predicted values.

Now we can just add two lines to the plots

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=as.POSIXct(index(df)))) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=predicted), col='red') + 
  geom_line(aes(y=actual), col='black') + 
  geom_line(aes(y=upr), col='blue') + 
  geom_line(aes(y=lwr), col='blue') + 
  theme_bw() +
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.POSIXct("1982-12-01")), 
      linetype="dashed") + 
  labs(title="Holt-Winters filtering\n", x="Time", y="Observed / Fitted") + 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"))
```

[image: holt winters gg2 plot]

Comment: (+1) For a shaded region around the prediction you can use `geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lwr,ymax=upr),alpha=0.3, fill="blue")`